# How to assign a char* to an array of char* with unique entries?

Tags: c, arrays

Okay so that wasn't very clear. What I am trying to do is this:

```
while (//something) {    
    char * tempuser;
    char * users[100];
    tempuser = "bobsmith" //I'm not actually doing this. But using a method that does the same thing
    users[i] = tempuser;
}
```

Where "bobsmith" is is different everytime through the loop. If I run this, as is, 5 times and the last entry is "janetsmith" all 5 places in the array before that, regardless of being different when assigned, all end up as "janetsmith".  How should I assign users[i] so that it has a different value in all indexes?

Comment: why don't you use `std::string`?

Comment: Oh my mistake, this is just c, not c++

Comment: @docx118 Why do you tag it as C++ when it's not about C++? Spamming tags is frowned upon on this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not create the array `users` in loop body, and use `strdup` to create new string with the same content inside the array. Remember that You are using **pointers** not some kind of string objects. Each entry in array holds the address of the text inside memory.

```
char *users[100]={0}; //one hundred pointers that are null so You don't use a wild one.
int i=0;
while(/*whatever*/) {
    char *tmp=getsometext(); //returns char pointer
    users[i++]=strdup(tmp); //copies contents pointed by tmp into new memory location and returns its address
}
//don't forget to free every pointer when You are done.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had already declared the array outside of the while loop but I added the loop in last on here and had forgotten. And strdup() worked great, I tried that before though and it didn't work. But now it did. Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't forget that I assumed that You want a duplicate in the array, in case that `getsometext()` returns a pointer to already heap allocated string You should just store it in the array. Usually functions don't return C strings but get a char pointer as parameter eg:`void getsometext(char* output)` at which they can store the result, just to make it clear to whoever writes the code that they are in charge of the memory.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are assigning address of the variable tempuser. By the end of it all, it will always hold the address of "janetsmith". Try creating the variable dynamically using malloc() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
char * users[100]; //with this you can use it outside while    
while (//something) {  

        static unsigned int i = 0;  
        //char * tempuser;

        //tempuser = "bobsmith" //I'm not actually doing this. But using a method that does the same thing
        users[i] = method_which_return_char_pointer();
        i++;
        if( 100 <= i)
          i=0;

    }
```

this what from your brief Question explanation .